# WordPress Elementor widget not in list

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I using **[Elementor](https://elementor.com/)** via `Press Elements` on WordPress to make my custom theme dynamic with making widget, It's my first time, I successed somehow, but there is a small problem, my widget not list in widget lists, but it find when I search via search bar, but I want to show in list by default, like the others.

I followed this steps to create widget, what I missed?

1. Create my php file for widget
2. assaign to `press-elements.php`

code:

```
    private function register_widgets()
    {
        \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register_widget_type( new \PressElements\Widgets\Members() );
    }
```

and:

```
    private function include_widgets()
    {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/widgets/Members.php';
}
```

That's all

This is list:

[image]

And when I search:

[image]

Comment: Did you define `get_categories` ? if true, share it.

Comment: @Pedram yes,  `public function get_categories() {
  return [ 'pmc-widget' ];
 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me look like you forget to register `category` in `press-elements.php`, search for `add_elementor_category()` function, add this line:

```
->add_category( 'pmc-widget', ['title' =>'PMC Widget',]
```

By this, all `widgets` under `pmc-widget` title, will be group in your list.

Comment: Thanks! it solved my issue! :) is there any documentation or guide to learn how to make widget? I just make it on my own with an example file.